# How to sum rows in groups of 3?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
id | amount
1  | 8
2  | 3
3  | 9
3  | 2
4  | 5
5  | 3
5  | 1
5  | 7
6  | 3
7  | 3
8  | 5
```

I need a query that returns the summed amount of rows grouped by every 3 consequent IDs. The result should be:

```
ids (not a necessary column, just to explain better) | amount
1,2,3 | 22
4,5,6 | 19
7,8 | 8
```

In my table, you can assume IDs are always consequent. So there can't be a 10 without existing a 9 too. But the same ID can also show up multiple times with different amounts (just like in my example above).

Comment: take the ceiling of ID / 3 and group by it. and sum amount.  `SELECT max(ID) maxID,  SUM(Amount) FROM TBLNAME GROUP BY Ceiling(ID/3) order by maxID`  All this is doing is grouping ID's into sets of 3 so 1-3 gets  assigned 1, 4-6 gets assigned 2 etc...  then it doesn't matter how many 5's or 4's there are; they all get the same grouping ID.  (Realized floor wouldn't' work because 1-3 wouldn't all become 0. where as ceiling they would all become 1.

Comment: Can you supply expected results? Groups of three doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming ID is a numeric data type.
[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=359e6393703b14e62d2547042a2917b6)

```
SELECT max(id) maxID,  SUM(Amount) as Amount
FROM TBLNAME 
GROUP BY Ceiling(id/3.0) 
ORDER BY maxID
```

Giving us:

```
+-------+--------+
| maxid | amount |
+-------+--------+
|     3 |     22 |
|     6 |     19 |
|     8 |      8 |
+-------+--------+
```

[Doc Link: Ceiling](https://www.w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/ceiling-function.php#:%7E:text=The%20PostgreSQL%20ceiling()%20is,as%20greater%20than%20the%20argument)

- MaxID is included just so the order by makes sense and validation of totals can occur.
- I used 3.0 instead of 3 and implicit casting to a decimal data type (a hack I know but it works)  otherwise integer math takes place and the rounding when the division occurs provides a incorrect result.

Without the .0 on the 3.0 divisor we'd get:

```
+-------+--------+
| maxid | amount |
+-------+--------+
|     2 |     11 |
|     5 |     27 |
|     8 |     11 |
+-------+--------+
```

`Ceiling()` is used over `floor()` since `floor()` would not allow aggregation of 1-3 in the same set.

Comment: And assuming IDS are consecutive without any gaps....

Comment: na, that was stated,. "can't have 10 w/o a 9" etc...

Comment: and the fact that id can be duplicated?

Comment: Not a problem since all 5's would get the same ceiling and they should be in the same group

Comment: you right consecutive IDS not rows.

Comment: All good questions to consider.  I may have made an assumption based on the original question  but I think I have the intent covered.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. thank you!